# Where do I configure the severity for R# code inspections?

Tags: c++, resharper, code-inspection

I currently get red squiggly lines for a non-explicit converting constructor. That's superb! My colleagues want that, too. Where the heck did I configure that?

I am quite sure that this is a Jetbrains Resharper for C++ features, because I can disable it via the light bulb and it adds

> // ReSharper disable once CppNonExplicitConvertingConstructor

I can't find such a setting in the Resharper Inspection options for C++:

[image: C++ inspection options]

My Resharper version is 2022.3.1. I'm using it in Visual Studio 17.5.3.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can configure the severity of the inspection either in "ReSharper | Options | Code inspection | Inspection severity" or from the Alt+Enter menu when the caret is inside the highlighted inspection range.
[image]
As expected, there's also a [help page](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/resharper/Code_Analysis__Configuring_Warnings.html#change_severity) which explains everything in depth